# Module Resolution: NPM Install Typescript package from Github

Tags: typescript, github, npm, module, package

So I want to fork an existing npm package, written in typescript, and mod it to my specific (non generally useful) needs.

I learned how npm also installs from github branches, no problem there.

But when I do so, module resolution doesn't work anymore (no modifications done). It does work perfectly with the original package and the same setup.

I suppose it has to do with the type definitions. I tried running `npm i @types/<name>` without luck, where  is the same name as the original package. The package doesn't seem to include the definitions in the package itself.

What do I have to do to make it work?? It seems so overly complicated..

Error I'm getting at compilation:

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find module '<name>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try importing directly from the `/src` directory, like this:

`import Frame from 'react-frame-component/src';`

I recently ran into a similar problem where I was trying to install a GitHub fork from [react-frame-component](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component). The package in my `node_modules` showed only a `/src` folder and no `/lib` folder like defined by the `main` field in *package.json*. I assume that's because the `npm run build` script for that package was only set to be called during the `prepublish` hook for NPM, so the `/lib` folder never got generated.